# Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cors

I have an app made with React, Node.js and Socket.io 
I deployed Node backend to heroku , frontend to Netlify

I know that CORS errors is related to server but no matter what I add, it just cant go through that error in the picture below. 
I also added  proxy   script to React's package.json as  "proxy": "https://googledocs-clone-sbayrak.herokuapp.com/"

[image: corserror]

And here is my `server.js` file;

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Document = require('./Document');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'https://googledocs-clone-sbayrak.netlify.app/',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  },
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('hello!!');
});

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const connect = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });

    console.log('MongoDB Connected...');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error : ${error.message}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

connectDB();


let defaultValue = '';

const findOrCreateDocument = async (id) => {
  if (id === null) return;

  const document = await Document.findById({ _id: id });

  if (document) return document;

  const result = await Document.create({ _id: id, data: defaultValue });
  return result;
};
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('get-document', async (documentId) => {
    const document = await findOrCreateDocument(documentId);
    socket.join(documentId);
    socket.emit('load-document', document.data);
    socket.on('send-changes', (delta) => {
      socket.broadcast.to(documentId).emit('receive-changes', delta);
    });

    socket.on('save-document', async (data) => {
      await Document.findByIdAndUpdate(documentId, { data });
    });
  });
  console.log('connected');
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () =>
  console.log(`Server has started.`)
);
```

and this is where I make request from frontend;

```
import Quill from 'quill';
import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const SAVE_INTERVAL_MS = 2000;
 

const TextEditor = () => {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState();
  const [quill, setQuill] = useState();
  const { id: documentId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const s = io('https://googledocs-clone-sbayrak.herokuapp.com/');
    setSocket(s);
     

    return () => {
      s.disconnect();
    };
  }, []); 

 /* below other functions */
 /* below other functions */
 /* below other functions */
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

[Web origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) do *not* contain a path.

Accordingly, `https://googledocs-clone-sbayrak.netlify.app/` is *not* a valid Web origin. Drop that trailing slash.

### More details about the problem

#### No trailing slash allowed in the value of the `Origin` header

According to the CORS protocol (specified in the [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/)), [browsers never set the `Origin` request header to a value with a trailing slash](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#origin-header). Therefore, if a page at `https://googledocs-clone-sbayrak.netlify.app/whatever` issues a cross-origin request, that request's `Origin` header will contain

```
https://googledocs-clone-sbayrak.netlify.app
```

without any trailing slash.

#### Byte-by-byte comparison on the server side

You're using [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/), [which relies on](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/) the [Node.js `cors` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors). That package won't set any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response if the request's origin doesn't exactly match your CORS configuration's `origin` value (`https://googledocs-clone-sbayrak.netlify.app/`).

#### Putting it all together

Obviously,

```js
'https://googledocs-clone-sbayrak.netlify.app' ===
'https://googledocs-clone-sbayrak.netlify.app/'
```

evaluates to `false`, which causes the `cors` package not to set any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response, which causes the CORS check to fail in your browser, hence the CORS error you observed.

#### Example from the Fetch Standard

Section 3.2.5 of the Fetch Standard even provides [an enlightening example](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-ascii-serialisation-of-an-origin%E2%91%A0) of this mistake,

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://rabbit.invalid/
```

and explains why it causes the CORS check to fail:

> A serialized origin has no trailing slash.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you haven't imported the cors package. Is it imported anywhere else?

```
var cors = require('cors') // is missing
```

Comment: It's there, `app.use(cors())`

Comment: thank you for notice, I have added but still getting the error

Comment: `app.use(cors())` is to use the cors package. But it is not imported, for which you need `const cors = require('cors')`  . Pls try this.

Comment: yes I have imported cors, it was missing; true. I redeployed but still does not work

Comment: Can you try to comment the code related to socket.io and just keep the app.use(cors()). This might work.

Comment: If it weren't imported the code wouldn't even start.