# CORS preflight request error on angular app deployed on heroku with node express backend

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku, cors

I have deployed an angular app on heroku (with the frontends and backend separated in multiple heroku apps) for a project at school and I'm stuck on an issue with CORS preflight requests.

Everytime I send a request to the backend I get the following error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://playlist-manager-backend.herokuapp.com/user/authenticate' from origin 'https://playlist-manager-admin.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here is the code of my server.js pushed on the backend app (playlist-manager-backend)

```
const express = require("express");
const { connect: dbconnect } = require("./src/db");
const { apiPort } = require("./src/config");
const routes = require("./src/routes");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
// Connect to the database
dbconnect();

// Create the server
const app = express();

// const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
// app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "5mb" }));
// app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World"));
const cors = require("cors");

/*let whitelist = ["https://playlist-manager-admin.herokuapp.com/","https://playlist- manager-user.herokuapp.com/"];*/

const corsOptions = {
    origin: ["https://playlist-manager-admin.herokuapp.com/", "https://playlist-manager-user.herokuapp.com/"],
    preflightContinue:false,
    credentials: true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));


app.use("/", routes);
app.use(express.static("./adverts"));

app.listen(apiPort, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${apiPort}`);
});
```

The routes to the backend functions are defined using router in the routes.js file like this.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const userRoute = require("../user/user.route");
const playlistRoute = require("../playlist/playlist.route");
const videoRoute = require("../video/video.route");
const annonceUploadRoute = require("../annoncesUpload/annoncesUpload.route");
const historyRoute = require("../history/history.route");
const advertiserRoute = require("../advertiser/advertiser.route");

router.use("/user", userRoute);
router.use("/playlist", playlistRoute);
router.use("/video", videoRoute);
router.use("/annoncesUpload", annonceUploadRoute);
router.use("/history", historyRoute);
router.use("/annonceur", advertiserRoute);

module.exports = router;
```

Here is an example of how routes are implemented :

```
router.post("/getById", async function(req, res) {
     const request = {
         _id: req.body._id,
     };
     const result = await bo.getById(request);
     res.send(result);
});
```

The frontend sends a post request to the backend using a service implemented like this :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export interface BackendData {
  success: string ;
  data: any ;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessageService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  sendMessage(Url:string, data:any): Observable<BackendData> {
    const serveur = environment.server + Url ;
    
    return this.http.post<BackendData>(
      serveur,
      data,
      {withCredentials: true}
    );
  }
}
```

I tried every solutions I saw online but I always got the same error or another error related to CORS policy.
I need help figuring out this behavior.
The app was working fine locally when I specified localhost with cors package like in the documentation.

Edit :
I removed slashes on the URL's and my server.js is like this :

```
const express = require("express");
const { connect: dbconnect } = require("./src/db");
const { apiPort } = require("./src/config");
const routes = require("./src/routes");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
// Connect to the database
dbconnect();

// Create the server
const app = express();

// const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
// app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "5mb" }));
// app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World"));
const cors = require("cors");

/*let whitelist = ["https://playlist-manager-admin.herokuapp.com/", "https://playlist-manager-user.herokuapp.com/"];*/

const corsOptions = {
  origin: ["https://playlist-manager-admin.herokuapp.com", "https://playlist-manager-user.herokuapp.com"],
  credentials: true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));


app.use("/", routes);
app.use(express.static("./adverts"));

app.listen(apiPort, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${apiPort}`);
});
```

[This is the network tab after sending the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSkcW.png)

[This is the xhr request shown in the network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwCP3.png)

[This is the preflight request in the network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmXCR.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep getting CORS error even if I set CORS origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/keep-getting-cors-error-even-if-i-set-cors-origin)

Comment: I removed the trailing slashes as the answer suggested but I got this error :   ```Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://playlist-manager-backend.herokuapp.com/user/authenticate' from origin 'https://playlist-manager-user.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.```   my code in the server.js is like this ```  const corsOptions = {
  origin: ["https://playlist-manager-admin.herokuapp.com", "https://playlist-manager-user.herokuapp.com"],
  credentials: true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions)); ```

Comment: What kind of request does `sendMessage` issue? Edit your question and add a screenshot of the request in question (and the response to it) from your browser's Network tab.

Comment: I edited my question with the requests that happened according to the network tab

Comment: This is no longer a CORS issue. You should investigate why you're now getting a 503. Fix that first.

Comment: I will check why do I still get a error telling me that there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header according to the console

Comment: The backend most likely fails with a 503 even before the CORS header gets added to the response. Since the preflight succeeds, and under the assumption that your CORS configuration be sound, I expect the required `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header will be present in the response once you fix that 503 issue.

Comment: I managed to trace back to the source of the error in the backend it was failing when connecting to the database because I forgot to add the environnement variables. Now it works thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jubObs comments I managed to fix this. The source of the problem was that the backend server wasn't starting which was causing a 503 status. I forgot to add the file defining the credentials for the database connections which caused the backend to fail before adding the headers.

here is the new server.js code :

```
const express = require("express");
const { connect: dbconnect } = require("./src/db");
const { apiPort } = require("./src/config");
const routes = require("./src/routes");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
// Connect to the database
dbconnect();

// Create the server
const app = express();

// const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
// app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "5mb" }));
// app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World"));
const cors = require("cors");

/*let whitelist = ["https://playlist-manager-admin.herokuapp.com/", "https://playlist-manager-user.herokuapp.com/"];*/

const corsOptions = {
   origin: ["https://playlist-manager-admin.herokuapp.com", "https://playlist-manager-user.herokuapp.com"],
   credentials: true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));


app.use("/", routes);
app.use(express.static("./adverts"));

app.listen(apiPort, () => {
   console.log(`Server is listening on port ${apiPort}`);
});
```

The database connection was using dotenv and the .env file that was defining the database credentials wasn't present in the main branch so I pushed it.
To figure this out I checked the application logs on heroku which are in "more" and "view logs".