# Golang Gorilla POST CORS hangs

Tags: cors, gorilla

A native go program causes my Linux system to run out of memory. Nothing hits any handler. I am using the gorilla CORS handler configured as follows:

```
        credentialsOk := gh.AllowCredentials()
        headersOk := gh.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type"})
        methodsOk := gh.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"})
        originsOk := gh.AllowedOrigins([]string{"localhost", "192.168.1.142", ".universalcharts.com", ".ihids.com"})
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+ep.Port, gh.CORS(originsOk, headersOk, methodsOk, credentialsOk)(router)))
```

A web sites hits the server and hangs until the system crashes for low of memory. I can cause it also with this simple curl command:
curl -X POST -F 'userName=user@example.com' -F 'password=password'  http://localhost:30100/api/rest/v1/auth/authorize

Wild card Origins causes it also.  I am at a loss, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the server crash is caused by gorilla's CORS middleware. Most likely, you have some memory leak in your server. However, one problem with your CORS configuration is that the origins you wish to allow are invalid Web origins.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)

Comment: I can remove the CORS handler and it does not hang. With it in the endpoint handler is never called. Without it, the endpoint is called and no hang.

Comment: Very interesting! I've retracted my close vote (though the issue about invalid origins remains). Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also, can you tell us which version of gorilla/handlers you're using (tag or commit) and perhaps share a crash dump, if you have one?

Comment: Well? Were you able to produce a MRE?