# Unable to resolve this CORS issue with a react frontend

Tags: c#, .net, cors

I have read multiple solutions but somehow none worked for me. I am still getting CORS error. I am using a react front end and tried all solutions related to the frontend. I think my problem has to do with the backend .NET

this is how my controller CORS settings look like. I tried the wild card but it does not work either, I am now trying with the frontend address and port and still having CORS issues. any suggestion ?

```
    [EnableCors(origins: ALLOWED_CORS_ORIGINS, headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
    public class TroubleshootingDataController : ApiController
    {
        private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        private const string ALLOWED_CORS_ORIGINS = "http://localhost:3000/";
```

startUp.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebAPI.Startup))]

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                //ConfigureAuth(app);
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HangfireConnection", new SqlServerStorageOptions { SchemaName = "HangfireConnLiving" });
                var filter = new BasicAuthAuthorizationFilter(
                    new BasicAuthAuthorizationFilterOptions
                    {
                        RequireSsl = true,
                        LoginCaseSensitive = true,
                        Users = new[]
                        {
                            new BasicAuthAuthorizationUser
                            {
                                Login = "",
                                PasswordClear = ""
                            }
                        }
                    });
                app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
                {
                    Authorization = new[]
                    {
                        filter
                    }
                });
                app.UseHangfireServer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)

Comment: I tried that. it did not work

Comment: Well, it was a misconfiguration; that's at least one problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the backend on the Startup.cs just add this

On configure.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder appBuilder, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
{
    appBuilder.UseCors(); // this line must before the appBuilder.UseEndPoints();
}
```

On ConfigureServices, we configure the cors

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
            builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            builder.AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });
}
```

Edit:

It seams you are using a diferent framework or something like that, that I'm used to work with.

try to add this

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

before the `if (!Debugger.IsAttached)`

Comment: my Startup.cs looks different I am going to edit my post with it.

Comment: It's worth noting that .UseCors() must be called before the endpoints are added. For example if you have .UseCors().UseEndpoints() then CORS will be used for those endpoints, if you have .UseEndpoints().UseCors() then the CORS middleware won't be reached in time.

Comment: @GHOST check my edit

Comment: Ty @JulianSildenLanglo forgot to mention that, going to edit to add this info

Comment: app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); error IAppBuilder does not contain a definition for UseCors, also CorsOptions does not contain a definition for AllowAll.

Comment: What is the version of the framework that you are using?