# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. React App Heroku API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I'm trying to integrate passport-google-oauth20 in my MERN application  and although everything works fine in development on my local host but in production, it keeps throwing this error;

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have searched and gone through multiple stack overflow posts and tried some of the answers and suggestions but nothing seems to work. This my index.js and the codes commented out are some of the solutions and CORS settings I've tried. I also tried putting the URL directly instead of an environment variable, but that didn't work either.

```
const express = require("express");
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const cors = require("cors");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth.route");
const userRoute = require("./routes/user.route");
const adminRoute = require("./routes/admin.route");
const transactionRoute = require("./routes/transaction.route");

//Passport setup
require("./passport");

const path = require("path");

// require("dotenv").config();
const app = express();

require("dotenv").config({
  path: "./config/config.env",
});

//Connect to Database
connectDB();

//Use bodyParser
app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: false,
    frameguard: true,
  })
);

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: "session",
    keys: ["ccurves"],
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 100,
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Config for only development
// if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
//   app.use(
//     cors({
//       origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
//       methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
//       credentials: true,
//     })
//   );
// }

// const corsOptions = {
//   origin: [`${process.env.CLIENT_URL}`],
//   methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS,POST,DELETE",
//   allowedHeaders: [
//     "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
//     "Origin",
//     "X-Requested-With",
//     "Content-Type",
//     "Accept",
//     "Authorization",
//     "token",
//     "Access-Control-Request-Method",
//     "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
//     "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
//   ],
//   credentials: true,
//   preflightContinue: false,
//   optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
// };
// app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
    methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

// app.use((req, res, next) => {
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}`);
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
//   res.header(
//     "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
//     "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, token, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
//   );

//   next();
// });

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/user", userRoute);
app.use("/api/admin", adminRoute);
app.use("/api/transaction", transactionRoute);

const port = process.env.PORT;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

And in my react frontend I'm fetching the request from the API like this:

```
 const getUser = () => {
      fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/login/success`, {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) return response.json();
          throw new Error("authentication has been failed!");
        })
        .then((resObject) => {
          authenticate(resObject, () => {
            isAuth && navigate("/");
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    };
```

I also tried using axios to send the request,

```
   axios
        .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/login/success`, {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          authenticate(res.data, () => {
            isAuth && navigate("/");
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          // setError(err.response.data.errors);
        });
```

And it works fine and perfectly on my local host, all other routes are working and even the other authentication method works fine. Why is this particular route been blocked by CORS? When I open the API URL `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/login/success` directly in the browser I can see the json data is been sent fine. What is going on? Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you confirm whether the `CLIENT_URL` in `environment` variable of heroku is set for the frontend domain

Comment: @Kaneki21 Yes I thought that was the issue too but I confirmed it, the CLIENT_URL is set

Comment: I know using `cors` package would be requiring code change, but can you try with that too, if the problem still persists. also are you serving react ui with the express or is it separate ?

Comment: Isn't the cors package for development alone? No the react app is hosted on vercel and the backend on heroku

Comment: no, `cors` can be used with production as well. You have to ensure you have all the origins listed properly so that any request from random origin cannot take place

Comment: @Kaneki21 this is the development config for cors I use, can I us this in production? app.use(
//     cors({
//       origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
//       methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
//       credentials: true,
//     })
//   );

Comment: What is the actual value of `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}`? Does it contain a path? It should not.

Comment: @ccurves I have added the alternate cors sample config as answer, give it a try

Comment: @jub0bs what do you mean it shouldn't contain a path? In production, it's my domain URL and in development localhost:3000

Comment: @ccurves It should be a valid Web origin (scheme, host, optional port). Did you mean `http://localhost:3000` as opposed to `localhost:3000`? Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow/70375725#70375725

Comment: Drop that `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header from your request. This is a _response_ header, not a _request_ header. Also, no point in listing `Origin` or all those `Access-Control-*` headers in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header.

Comment: @jub0bs yes I meant http://localhost:3000 and I dropped the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header from the request and aslo checked but the URL doesn't have a trailing slash

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Kaneki21 Solution actually worked for me but he has deleted his answer so I'm reposting it. All credits go to him, so this cors configuration solved the error:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: [`${process.env.CLIENT_URL}`],
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS,POST,DELETE",
  allowedHeaders: [
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin",
    "X-Requested-With",
    "Content-Type",
    "Accept",
    "Authorization",
    "token",
    "Access-Control-Request-Method",
    "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
  ],
  credentials: true,
  preflightContinue: false,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

But I ran into another issue, Although the request was sent now, I noticed cookies weren't included in the header even after I added `withCredentials: true`. Inspecting the request in the chrome network tab I could see the cookies was been filtered out. I solved that by switching from cookie-session to express-session and using this config:

```
app.set("trust proxy", 1); // trust first proxy
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
    },
  })
);
```

Notice the `sameSite: "none"` in the cookie configuration, that enables cross-sites request and it requires secure to be true. Previously cookie-session wasn't setting the sameSite attribute even when I included it in the cookie config and browsers set  `Lax` as a default so hence the switch to express-session. You can check out these sites to understand more [site1](https://w3guides.com/tutorial/cookies-not-being-sent-despite-credentials-include) [site2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite)

I hope this helps someone out cause I know this gave me quite a bit of a headache