# CORS Even After Enabling

Tags: reactjs, .net, azure-functions, cors

I am developing a web application with react. To call the API's I am using HTTP triggers in Azure function apps. All the API's are working without an issue. I am in the integrating process. I came across this CORS issue. I have tried to overcome this but I am still getting the same error. and I dont have an express.js

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                      });
});


// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<EmployeeDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeDB")));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

ReactApp

```
const makeAPICall = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:7182/api/GetEmployees', {mode:'cors'});
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log({ data })
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  makeAPICall();
}, [])
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>React Cors Guide</h1>
  </div>
);
}
```

[image]

Updated

I found out that the problem is Missing Header.

[image]

Comment: You can add the method and header option as well in your Cors options service to '*' to accept all header.

Comment: I did that but still did not work @Red-Dot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)

Comment: No, I don't have express server. I have different problem @jub0bs

Comment: The backend technology is irrelevant. Whether you're using Express or .NET, you cannot reasonable expect a CORS middleware to work properly if you don't specify a valid Web origin. `http://localhost:3000/` is not a valid Web origin; you need to drop that trailing slash.

Comment: I tried removing the / but still, it is not working updated the question @jub0bs

Comment: That screenshot of your browser's Network tab does not show a CORS request/response. Otherwise, the request would contain an `Origin` header.

Answer (score 0):

Middlewares like this have to be places in the pipeline in correct order and sometimes other middlewares have to be enabled

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order

According to your issue, it seems that app.UseRouting() is missing (may be something else, article above definitely knows it better)