# How to use fastify-cors and node JS to allow multiple urls in cors origin

Tags: node.js, cors, fastify

My URL list look like this

```
const urls = ["example1.com", "exam.com"]
```

My cors setting look like this:

```
  const cors = require("fastify-cors")

  // Enable CORS
  fastify.register(cors, {
    origin: '*',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    credentials: true
  })
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Likely relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow/70375725#70375725

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fastify-cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-cors) has been deprecated.  Please use [@fastify/cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fastify/cors) instead.

For your version, this is the [documentation](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cors/tree/v7.0.0#options).

```
const cors = require("fastify-cors")
const urls = ["example1.com", "exam.com"]

// Enable CORS
fastify.register(cors, {
  origin: urls,
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  credentials: true
})
```

Comment: I went used my origin set to be only for my list of URLs.

Answer (score 0):

From the `Fasify-Cors` docs you can use array in origin option. [Read for more](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cors#options)

Your example could be:

```js
const cors = require("@fastify/cors")

  // Enable CORS
  fastify.register(cors, {
    origin: ["example1.com", "exam.com"],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    credentials: true
  })
```