# Firebase functions + Firebase hosting with Angular CORS issue

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors, nestjs

I have a Firebase project, where I have a NestJS application deployed to Firebase functions. In this very same project I have an Angular application deployed to Firebase hosting, and finally I have a Firebase Realtime Database in the same Firebase project.

My issue is, that the deployed or locally served Angular application fails to call my functions endpoint due to CORS error, however this endpoint is callable from Postman's desktop client without a problem and the data returns properly if I open the endpoint from a browser.

The error message is the following in the console, in my deployed Angular application:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-my-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/api/endpoint/' from origin 'https://my-project-name.firebaseapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

**What I've tried so far**

In my NestJS application's `main.ts` I've tried the following solutions:

**Solution 1**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'https://my-project-name.firebaseapp.com/',
    methods: 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE',
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Authorization',
  });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

**Solution 2**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

**Solution 3**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

None of them worked. I'm still able to call the endpoint from Postman or by opening the endpoint from the browser.

I've tried to use Angular HTTP Client, Axios and even fetch API but all of them returns the same error. I've tried to pass the following headers as well:

```
fetch('https://us-central1-my-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/api/endpoint/,
      {
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
```

```
fetch('https://us-central1-my-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/api/endpoint/, { mode: 'no-cors' })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
```

But no luck. What do I do wrong? Thanks for the help in advance!

**UPDATE**

I've completely removed the headers from my request. The fetch now looks like the followings:

```
fetch('https://us-central1-my-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/api/endpoint/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
```

NestJS `main.ts` looks like the following:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
    origin: ['https://my-project-name.firebaseapp.com', 'http://localhost:4200'],
    methods: 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE',
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Authorization',
  });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

And the error is the same.

**UPDATE 2**

[image: Network tab]

**Update 3**

Okay, I've found what caused the issue. For whatever reason in my NestJS project, in the root folder there was a `main.ts` and an `index.ts` file. Firebase functions is looking for the `index.ts` file. So no matter I've made the required CORS related changes, they didn't work.

As soon as I've deleted my `main.ts` and applied **Solution 2**, so `app.enableCors()` in the `index.ts` file and redeployed everything, the aforementioned error has gone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)

Comment: I've removed the trailing slash from my origin (see Solution 1), but I still get the same error.

Comment: Good. Another problem is that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` doesn't belong in the request, since it's a _response_ header. It's especially problematic because your CORS configuration doesn't list that header name in the `allowedHeaders` property. Simply drop that header from your request.

Comment: Edit your question and add details there, not in comments.

Comment: Edited and added an **UPDATE** section there.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your browser's Network tab showing the problematic preflight request (including its headers).

Comment: Added it to **Update 2** section.

Comment: Any chance you were able to take a look?

Comment: Well, according to your screenshot, the request's origin ends in `.web.app`. However, according to your code snippet, no such origin is allowed by your CORS configuration. That's likely the problem.

Comment: I've found the issue, see the updated post. Thank you for your kind assist though.