# CORS issue in Nest JS

Tags: express, cors, nestjs

I am building an app in Nest JS, and the front-end is in React.

I have this CORS setting in the main.ts file:

```
const whitelist = [
  process.env.APP_WEBSITE_URL as string,
  process.env.APP_URL as string,
  process.env.SUPER_TOKEN_CONNECTION_STRING as string,
  'http://localhost:3000/' as string,
];
app.enableCors({
  origin: whitelist,
  allowedHeaders: ['content-type', ...supertokens.getAllCORSHeaders()],
  credentials: true,
  methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH'],
});
```

My front-end is running on  `app.jetabe.com` and backend on `api.jetabe.com`

I am getting this error: `Access to fetch at 'https://api.jetabe.com/applicationType' from origin 'https://app.jetabe.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'https://app.jetabe.com, *', but only one is allowed. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

It is adding the * in the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**. I have no idea where that's coming from.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: One issue with your config is that `http://localhost:3000/` is not a valid origin. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow/70375725#70375725

Comment: Regarding the problem you're experiencing, some server in the chain is likely adding an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, which the browser then folds into the header of the same name that is set by Nest.js's CORS middleware. You need to find out which server is doing that.

Comment: @jub0bs sorry, but I do't understand this: Regarding the problem you're experiencing, some server in the chain is likely adding an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, which the browser then folds into the header of the same name that is set by Nest.js's CORS middleware. You need to find out which server is doing that.

Comment: Some reverse proxy is likely adding that extra `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

Comment: @jub0bs I am not using reverse-proxy.

Comment: Well, in all likelihood, some server is adding that header, and it's not because of the CORS configuration you're showing in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue with cors,
I solved it using :

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    cors: true,
});
```