# CORS issue with .NET 6 Web API debug in VS and React in VS Code debug in the same project directory

Tags: c#, reactjs, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, vscode-debugger

I'm having CORS issue when I use React to upload a file in POST Method. Using Postman works fine. Other API Endpoints using POST, GET, PUT all works as long as there's no file upload.

I've added a Proxy in package.json  - "**proxy": "https://127.0.0.1:7224/**" and even tried  - "**start": "cross-env DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true react-scripts start**"

Below the react code, I've also tried it without "headers"

```
 imageUpload = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", e.target.files[0], e.target.files[0].name);

        fetch('/api/Employee/SaveFile', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            headers : { 
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain'
               }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ PhotoFileName: data });
            })
    }
```

Program.cs

```
//Enable CORS
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "orgEmpPolicy",
                policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000/", "http://192.168.1.9:3000/", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/")
                    .WithHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentType)
                    .WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "PATCH", "POST");
                });
});


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("orgEmpPolicy");
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
        [Route("SaveFile")]        
        public JsonResult SaveFile()
        {
            try
            {
                var httpRequest = Request.Form;
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[0];
                string filename = postedFile.FileName;


                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_env.WebRootPath))
                {
                    _env.WebRootPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");
                }

                var uploads = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Photos");
                var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, postedFile.FileName);

                if (!Directory.Exists(uploads))
                    _ = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));

                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(stream);
                }

                return new JsonResult(filename);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new JsonResult(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

It will work if I use Postman, but Swagger endpoints and react doesn't. Setup is that I'm debugging the WebAPI and then I debug react, everything works  except the file upload.

Network tab: Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/Employee/SaveFile from localhost:3000 to "https://127.0.0.1:7224/" (ECONNREFUSED).

[Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY2xp.png)

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmlcf.png)

-- Running debug on both React in VS Code and the Web API on Visual Studio 2022 first.

Comment: Not super familiar but in the CORS setup you have a line which contains “ PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "PATCH", wouldn’t you also want POST? I might be completely wrong.

Comment: CORS is something that gets enforced by the browser, which is why it works in Postman but not the browser.

Comment: Your action has the `HttpPostAttribute` applied to it which means that it will only match requests that use the POST method. Your CORS policy `orgEmpPolicy` does __not__ include the POST method and will therefore not match the policy and be subject to normal CORS rules. Try adding `"POST"` to the list of methods and see what happens.

Comment: You can try with:

services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Open", builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000/")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());

            });

Comment: I've tried " .AllowAnyMethod() .AllowAnyHeader() .AllowCredentials()", I've added "POST" method. Again, all the Methods work including POST - just not when I include file/image upload. I have a create "Employee" controller with a POST and it will save/create the record just fine. Perhaps it doesn't like the fact that I'm running the backend on the same location as the React Front end?

Comment: you sure this isn't due to an error when processing the file (500 error there...).  I suspect this line: stream.CopyTo(stream);  You're not using postedFile.CopyTo(stream).

Comment: @pcalkins, no it works fine with Postman. It's a CORS issue I'm sure of it. I bet it will work if I publish the API and have the React app accessing it elsewhere - I just want to be able to debug both on the same machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)

Comment: None of `http://localhost:3000/`, `http://192.168.1.9:3000/`, and `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` are valid Web origins: origins do not contain a path; see the table in https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials. [Ideally](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#5-validate-configuration-and-fail-fast), .NET's CORS middleware should fail when you specify invalid Web origins in your CORS config, but that's sadly not the case, and this lack of validation makes for a terrible developer experience.

Comment: @jub0bs, I've taken out the trailing forward slash and the file upload still doesn't work. I post without the file and it works fine. Incidentally, I have Swagger and everything there works fine but testing with file upload will fail it. The only thing that works is Postman for uploading files.

Comment: @AdonisVillanueva Ok, but look at the bright side: you're one step closer to solving your CORS issue. What CORS error message are you getting now? And is the problematic request preceded by a preflight request?

Comment: another possibility is it's enforcing a secure connection... the allowed origins are all http.  That doesn't explain why it works without the file, though.... maybe one has credentials and the other doesn't?

Comment: @pcalkins, yeah it's driving me crazy. I thought it's just me but I've cloned projects from other developers with the same setup but mine just doesn't work with file upload.

Comment: In case somebody's interested here's the Web API repo: https://github.com/AdonisVillanueva/OrganizationEmployeeAPI and the React client: https://github.com/AdonisVillanueva/react-organization-employee

Comment: From the current code in your question, I don't find any error about your CORS configuration in backend, From your description, The error only show how when you upload file in frontend, I am not sure if there is any error in your frontend.

Comment: You might just drop setting headers from your ajax call.  So remove:  headers : { 
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain'
               }  Headers will already be sent by the browser and one of those values will be origin.