# Why is cors error present even with added response header hosted heroku server

Tags: express, heroku, cors, mern

I created a full stack MERN application and have a server hosted on heroku. When using the hosted URL I keep getting a CORS error, preventing my front end from accessing my API:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://perf2-api.herokuapp.com/oils/6411f65e4ed9306f3e4921bf' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I’ve scoured the internet at this point including this site and kind of at my wits end. No solution has worked. I am using cors locally on the server port I’m have with no problems  (http://localhost:8082/)

Mainly the only one I have seen but not tried involves creating my own proxy on Heroku, but I was a bit confused on how to do so and doubted if this was necessary

Has anyone experienced this or have a solution??

Most solutions I have seen involve using a response header in different ways and I’ve tried different combinations in my code, basically everything I’ve seen. Here are some examples:

1.

```
     app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port 
     ${port}`));

     app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://perf2- 
    api.herokuapp.com/");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, PATCH, 
     GET, DELETE");
    return res.status(200).json({});
    }

     res.sendStatus(200);
   });
```

2. 

```
      app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
      next();
     });
```

3. 

```
     app.options('/*', (req, res, next) => {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 
   'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, 
   Authorization,            
         Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
        res.sendStatus(200);
      });
```

Here are my current server.js file imports and middleware

```
  const path = require("path");
  const express = require("express");
  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
  const logger = require("morgan");
  const cors = require("cors");
  const app = express();
  const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, 
  "frontend/perfumery2_client/build");
  const oilRoutes = require("./routes/api/oils");
  const connectDB = require("./config/db");

  const corsOptions = {
    credentials: true,
    origin: "*"
   }

     app.use((req, res, next) => {
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     res.header(
     "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
     "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, PATCH, 
   GET, DELETE");
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS" || "OPTIONS" === req.method) {
   return res.status(200).json({});
   }
   next();
  });
```

Mainly the only one I have seen but not tried involves creating my own proxy on Heroku, but I was a bit confused on how to do so and doubted if this was necessary

Has anyone experienced this or have a solution??

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow

Answer (score 0):

You can try [npm cors package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) as middleware instead of your custom middleware. CORS package allows you multiple configure and it's very easy to use.

```
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';

const app = express()
app.use(cors()); // <---- use cors middleware
```

Comment: Hi, I'm importing cors already in my server.js file . I've updated my question to show this