# CORS error when switching between www and non-www url even though my origins are listed in my Google Cloud Bucket's CORS origin array

Tags: google-app-engine, cors, google-cloud-storage, sveltekit

I have an application on Google App Engine with a public storage bucket that has the following CORS settings

```
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "HEAD"], "origin": ["https://[app-name].appspot.com", "https://subdomain.domain.com", "https://www.subdomain.domain.com"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"]}]
```

Everything works as expected when visiting these URL's separately, BUT if I visit  https://www.subdomain.domain.com/, then I visit my site at https://subdomain.domain.com/ (without clearing cache), I get CORS errors for all previously fetched assets from the bucket...

```
Access to fetch at 'https://[CDN_URL]/[ASSET_PATH]/image.jpg' from origin 'https://www.subdomain.domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://subdomain.domain.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

If I clear my cache and visit https://subdomain.domain.com/, no CORS errors.

In the scenario that's giving me errors, I'm wondering why it is listing my origin as 'https://www.subdomain.domain.com' when I've visited at 'https://subdomain.domain.com'. And also, why is there a CORS error when the bucket has both www and non-www urls in the origin array?

Can I solve this issue within the CORS config for the bucket or is there something else at play here?

FWIW, I'm using a SvelteKit framework for this application.

Comment: FYI it's usually referred to as "CORS" with a capital S, since it's an acronym for "Cross Origin Resource Sharing".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)

Comment: @jub0bs Thanks - I removed the trailing slashes suggested in the linked answer, but the issue remains.

Comment: @JohnnySlack Do you get the exact same error message, or is it different this time?

Comment: @jub0bs same one

Comment: @JohnnySlack Does the response contain a `Vary: Origin` header? Also, why are you requesting an image via an AJAX request?

Comment: @jub0bs Fetch is used because its loading textures for a WebGL experience. The images aren't going into a DOM. When the request is successful the response contains `Vary: Accept-Encoding,Origin`

Comment: When the browser makes the GET request, which request Origin header, if any, is sent?

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough When I visit `https://subdomain.domain.com` the request origin is also `https://subdomain.domain.com`. But the `Access-control-allow-origin` in the response header is `https://www.subdomain.domain.com`

Comment: Does it also fail if you use HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough Yes - the issue is there for either protocol