# Spring boot POST Request Error. Blocking CORS Policy

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, rest, cors

I am trying to call an Endpoint I created with Spring boot. (Completely new to Spring boot)
Everything work fine when I call the endpoint via POSTMAN (The whole CRUD process).
For the sake of testing I also made a small Vue app to test the endpoint.

The GET Request works fine, I get an Object back. When I try to make a POST request I get this Error Message:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/saveorder/' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

The Controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:5173/")
public class OrderController {

@Autowired
private OrderRepository orderRepository;

@Autowired
private ProductRepository productRepository;


@GetMapping("/orders/{id}")
public Order fetchOrder(@PathVariable long id) {
    return orderRepository.findById(id).get();
}

@PostMapping("/saveOrder")
public String saveOrder(@RequestBody Order order){
    Product product = productRepository.findById(order.getItemId()).get();

    order.setTotalPrice(new BigDecimal(product.getCost()).multiply(new BigDecimal(order.getQty())).longValue());
    order.setTotalPrice(order.getTotalPrice() / 100);
    orderRepository.save(order);
    return "Order Saved... total ";
}
```

}

And this would be the JS function:

```
const postInput = async () => {



try {
    const requestData = {
      firstName: inputItemFirstName.value,
      lastName: inputItemLastName.value,
      itemId: inputItemID.value
    }

    
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/saveorder/', requestData)
    outputText.value = JSON.stringify(response.data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)

Comment: In addition to dropping the trailing slash in `@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:5173/")`, you'll likely need to allow request header `Content-Type` in your CORS configuration.

Comment: Have you enabled any CORS-related headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your allowed origin is set to port 5173, but you are posting requests using port 8080

Try to replace

```
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:5173/")
```

With

```
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:8080")
```

No need for / after port number since you already have it at

```
@RequestMapping("/api")
```

Also your post url in JS has /saveorder/ but you have mapped /saveOrder 'O' is lowercase and uppercase respectively

In JS try to replace

```
http://localhost:8080/api/saveorder/
```

with

```
http://localhost:8080/api/saveOrder
```

Comment: The part with the Trailing slash in JS was the Problem. 
Thank you very much !

Answer (score -3):

Try to send header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' for server method and js function. Also you can use "npm package proxy" for your local application.

Comment: Since the backend is Java-based, I don't see how an npm package would help.