# Is overriding Quarkus HTTP configuration from .env file safe?

Tags: http, security, environment-variables, cors, quarkus

I have a container image of a Quarkus application that exposes a HTTP SSE end-point. This container is to be run in a Docker Composer stack that also hosts an UI. I would like to enable CORS and define allowed origins. As per the [configuration guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus-vertx-http-eclipse-vert.x-http), the parameters can be set at both the `application.properties` level and via an `.env` file.

Suppose, I have the following configuration in my `application.properties` file.

```bash
quarkus.http.cors=true
quarkus.http.cors.origins=http://localhost:3000/
```

As per the [precedence described here](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#configuration-sources), I can override CORS with environment variable `QUARKUS_HTTP_CORS=false`. While in some cases, it helps to override configuration using environment variables, I am not sure, this example is 'secure'.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Regardless of where it's done, a CORS configuration is only secure to the extent that it not be too permissive. Side-comment: `http://localhost:3000/` is _not_ a valid Web origin; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70375725/2541573

Comment: Copied the origin example from Quarkus guide. https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus.http.cors.origins

Comment: Where? I don't see any mention of `http://localhost:3000/` on the page in question.