# e.g the session id cookie is not sent after it is set when i login in the browser but is sent in subsequent requests in postman

Tags: node.js, express, cors, nestjs, session-cookies

i was working on a problem where i need a session to autenticate my users , i am using nest.js with passport for this autentication problem. The problem is when i use my /login endpoint it successfully return a setCookie header in postman and browser, but when i try to use this cookie for subsequent requests to protected routes it works fine in postman, but the cookie is not sent over in the browser your text

here is my main.ts file in nest js

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.use(cookieParser());

// **here is the code for setting the session -----**
 app.use(
    session({
      secret: 'keyboard',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
      
      },
    }),
  );

//------------

 
 app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-total-count');
    next();
  });
  app.enableCors({
    origin: ['http://127.0.0.1:3000','http://localhost:3000/'],
    credentials: true,
  });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

here is the guard code that cheks if  a session is present in the request

**autenticated.guard.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    console.log(request.session);
    return request.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

the console.log statement above produces the foolowing code both in the browser and postman

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-07-24T07:05:51.706Z,
    originalMaxAge: 600000,
    httpOnly: true,
```

**but the guard returns true for the same request in postman, but false in the browser**

here is the endpoint that uses this guard

```
@UseGuards(AuthenticatedGuard)
  @Patch('edit/:id')
  edit(
    @Param('id') id: string,
    @Body() editedData: EditAgentDto,
    @Request() req,
  ) {
    console.log(editedData)
    if (id === req.user.id) {
      return this.agentService.editAgent(id, editedData);
    }
  }
```

here is the guard that i use when a user loges in

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalAgentGuard extends AuthGuard('agent') {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const result = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean;
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    await super.logIn(request);
    return result;
  }
}
```

and here is the endpoint that uses the guard

```
@UseGuards(LocalAgentGuard)
  @Post('login')
  login(@Request() req) {
    return req.user;
  }
```

this end point successfuly sets the session cookie

here is my front end code that uses the patch http method with axios

**dashboard.tsx**

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios.patch(`http://localhost:3000/agents/edit/64bcc86e51ce7016ffb3d6c8`,data,{withCredentials: true})
          .then((res) =>{
  
            toast.success('your data has been saved')
            console.log(res)
            resolve();
          }
          )
          .catch(() => {
  
            toast.error('something went wrong')
            console.log('error')
            reject()
          } 
          );

        })
          
      }
```

the id parameter above is just for illustration purposes and it is valid id in the database,
when the request is sent the server responds with forbidden 403 exception

here is the port of my frontend

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server:{
    host:'localhost',
    port:3000,
  },
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

please guys i really need your help on this one if there is any information u want me to add ask me tnk u

i  expected for the cookie to be available on subsequent requests but it is not available in the browser

Comment: `SameSite=None` also requires `Secure` in Chrome.

Comment: i tried it not working!

Comment: Well, you won't be able to set a `Secure` cookie on `http://localhost`.

Comment: Also, your CORS configuration is incorrect: `http://localhost:3000/` is not a valid Web origin. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer , you should first use https server over http in order browsers to use the cookie that is set for sub sequent requests. in order to chang http to https, you can use tools like mkcert which are found in npm then configure your code like this :

```
const httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./secrets/create-cert-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./secrets/create-cert.pem'),
};

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    httpsOptions
  });
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Content-Type, Authorization',
    );
    next();
  });
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(
    session({
      secret: 'keyboard',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000,
       
        // httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        secure: true,
      },
    }),
  );

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-total-count');
    next();
  });
  app.enableCors({
    origin: ['http://127.0.0.1:5000'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH'],
    credentials: true,
  });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

where the files in the secrets folder are generated by mkcert