# AWS response includes "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" without using -X options (preflight request)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

As per my understanding, for CORS, we need to send a pre-flight request (OPTIONS request) in order to receive these headers in response :
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
Access-Control-Allow-Origin

[AWS OPTIONS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTOPTIONSobject.html)

Request and response in below format :

**Request** :

```
curl -i https://example.com/object.txt.txt  -H "Origin: http://localhost/" -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' -X OPTIONS
```

**Response** :

```
....
...
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, DELETE
....
....
```

However, when trying to access an object in AWS, I am able to get these response headers even **without passing -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' -X OPTIONS in request.**

**My request :**
`curl -i https://example.com/object.txt  -H "Origin: http://localhost/"`

**My response :**

```
....
....
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, DELETE
....
....
```

Wanted to know if AWS internally sends a preflight request with OPTIONS request or my understanding is incorrect.

PS: I am very new to AWS/CORS. Any kind of suggestion would be helpful.

CORS configuration for my bucket :

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "GET",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Comment: Side note: `http://localhost` is a valid Web origin, but `http://localhost/` is not. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is incorrect.

1. Not all requests are preflighted: [simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) are sent directly without an OPTIONS preflight. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` still applies to the response of these requests. This means that CORS headers are expected on the responses to some GET, HEAD, and POST requests.
2. A server is free to set CORS headers on any response it wants, even if it's totally unnecessary. In many cases the simplest thing to do is to add a fixed set of CORS headers to *every* response, without thinking about whether a request is a preflight, or requires a preflight, or has any CORS-related request headers. This is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
So in AWS, when I send my request as 
curl -i https://example.com/object.txt  i.e. without -H "Origin: http://localhost/" , I do not see any of these response headers : 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, DELETE

So is it like when we include -H "Origin: http://localhost/" , AWS sends both Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, DELETE as response?