# 400 error policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin on call to SAML IDP from .NET Core 6 app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, cors, saml-2.0

I'm trying to call https://stubidp.sustainsys.com as a SAML IDP and authenticate. This project uses the SAML nuget package from https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml.

Probably something stupid and simple, but I've spent many hours, and hoping someone else can see it.

The error returned is:

> Status 400
> Bad Request
> Version HTTP/2
> Transferred 5.16 kB (0 B size)
> Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin

I have this in my program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Policy1",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/");
        });
});
```

And this in my `login.cshtml.cs`:

```
using MainApp.Models;
using Saml;

namespace MainApp.Pages.Account;

[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        var context = HttpContext;
        var samlEndpoint = "https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/e64887c8-c492-49e3-94d5-08d4471ee265/";

        var request = new AuthRequest(
            "https://localhost:11123", //TODO: put your app's "entity ID" here
            "https://localhost:11123/Account/Consume" //TODO: put Assertion Consumer URL (where the provider should redirect users after authenticating)
        );

        //now send the user to the SAML provider
        return Redirect(request.GetRedirectUrl(samlEndpoint));
    }
}
```

And the POST received back is handled here:

```
using MainApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Saml;

namespace MainApp.Pages.Account;

[AllowAnonymous]
public class ConsumeModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IUserManager _userManager;
    //private readonly IRoleRepository _roleRepo;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public ConsumeModel(IUserManager userManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGet(string SAMLart)
    {
    }

    [EnableCors("Policy1")]
    public void OnPost()
    {
        // 1. TODO: specify the certificate that your SAML provider gave you
        string samlCertificate = @"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICFTCCAYKgAwIBAgIQzfcJCkM1YahDtRGYsLphrDAJBgUrDgMCHQUAMCExHzAd
BgNVBAMTFnN0dWJpZHAuc3VzdGF etc...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

        // 2. Let's read the data - SAML providers usually POST it into the "SAMLResponse" var
        Saml.Response samlResponse = new Response(samlCertificate, Request.Form["SAMLResponse"]);

        // 3. We're done!

        var username = "";

        if (samlResponse.IsValid())
            username = samlResponse.GetNameID();
```

Here is the IDP's SAML request data:

[image]

Comment: This may be a CORS issue.  See : https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/17288

Comment: Definitely a CORS issue. But I have put in the EnableCors attributes and it is still not working. I can see in the dev console that the response is making it back, and not accepted.

Comment: You may need an admin to change the CORS policy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)

Comment: I had added the EnableCors attribute, and I thought that was sufficient, but I'm wondering if I need to set the header that I'm posting to the IDP with an Access-Control-Allow-XXX value in addition.

Comment: I think this is not the cors error reported by your app, but the error reported by the identity provider. I never used `stubidp` but I used Azure AD before. At first I think I just need to send sign in request via ajax to get authenticated, but I got cors error as a response, AAD required me to use its own library to get authenticated. So I think you might face the same situation. In my humble opinion, you might looking for the official tutorial for the `stubidp` and see how to integrate it into your .net 6 application.

Comment: The stub IDP is returning the auth SAMLResponse data. I will add that to my question. Pretty sure the issue is in my client handling that somehow.