# I have static app on azure which is calling apis from web app on azure.Getting cors error inspite of haviong cors middleware added

Tags: javascript, azure, cors, fastapi

Access to fetch at 'https://itemapp.azurewebsites.net//items/list' from origin 'https://thankful-river-01992e00f.3.azurestaticapps.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from db import Base,engine
from item import router
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()
origins = [
    "https://thankful-river-01992e00f.3.azurestaticapps.net/"
]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],`your text`
)
app.include_router(router, prefix="/items")
#create all tables
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
'''
```

Comment: tried above code

Comment: Have you tried setting the CORS rules on the App Service? It also has CORS configuration.

Comment: Check what the actual response shows, and verify that you're returning a non-error response on the URL (a 500 error won't get CORS headers attached inside FastAPI for example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)

Comment: Web origins do not contain a path; drop that trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **[@jub0bs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)** and **@juunas** Thank you for your comments.

*Make sure you do not include trailing slash / in your code so the origin does not evaluate itself as false and disallow the CORS connection.*

**Updated code:-**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from db import Base, engine
from item import router
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()
origins = [
    "https://thankful-river-01992e00f.3.azurestaticapps.net"
]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)
app.include_router(router, prefix="/items")

# Create all tables
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

Also, Make sure you have added your **static web app url** in the **App Service CORS** and even while adding the **url here Slashes are not allowed**, Refer below:-

[image]