# How to set CORS headers properly?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cors

I am struggling to overcome the CORS restrictions and any pointers would be helpful.

The overall infrastructure map is as follows:

- mydomain.com on HostPapa/Wordpress, with Wordpress setup on the main mydomain.com address.
- subdomain.mydomain.com hosts an application which should be able to receive POST requests from a specific domain: develop.myotherdomain.com
- HostPapa's file manager shows: \subdomain\cgi-bin\myPOSTHandler.py, which is a working script handler, but with nothing on CORS
- a served page on develop.myotherdomain.com with a button that sends an XHR Post request from https://develop.myotherdomain.com/POSTRequester

This above setup fails with CORS with Firefox logging a console error: (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I read up on the solution suggesting the addition of an .htaccess file in \subdomain which says:
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://develop.myotherdomain.com/"

However, this hasn't worked to resolve the CORS error. I cannot find any syntax rules for the .htaccess file, not sure if the above line is correct, and have tried variations (add instead of set, use of ":" and also removal of quotes, put .htaccess in every folder of the subdomain) based on similar posts I've read.

My only current workaround is to use Chrome as follows: chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://mytesting" --disable-web-security

Eventually, it all moves to subdomain.mydomain.com and the POST requests are known to work fine.

I need a better way to fix CORS so that the dev work can continue on the develop.myotherdomain.com

I know enough about CORS, but can't understand how to make Apache (underlying to Hostpapa) handle CORS header setting to allow requests from one very specific domain.

Thanks.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment from [jub0bs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541573/jub0bs), and additional information digging here are the ways to deal with a similar problem:

1. Server under your control situation (like HostPapa in my case), i.e. you have edit access on the server at mydomain.com and your app is running on subdomain.mydomain.com :
   Solution: Place a .htaccess file in the folder structure \subdomain with the following entry:

`Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://develop.myotherdomain.com"`

The main trip point here is the "Origin" used by the browser to do a CORS Preflight check. You can normally see this entry in the browser console. In Firefox, this appears under Console>Network >selecting the specific POST/(?) request and checking the entry under the Headers>Request Headers>Origin. This exact origin (without anything extra or less) has to be added to the above entry.

2. If all else fails (or main server not under your control), **and** the request doesn't need exchange of credentials/cookies (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin)), you can use crossOrigin="anonymous" in your client-side Javascript like this:

```
const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
XHR.addEventListener("load", function (event) {//load handling
 console.log("DEBUG: XHR Response", this.response);
});

XHR.addEventListener("error", function (event) {//error handling
 console.log(event);
});

//the next line is important... do it before XHR.open though(?)
XHR.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

XHR.open("POST", yourURLPath);
```

3. Never set Allow Origin to "*" on main server unless you have a really good understanding of why you are allowing everyone on the internet to access the resource from your server. (this was somewhat the origin of my question, as I didn't want to set it to "*" as many examples tell you to)