# Getting CORS Error - Multiple Allow Origin values in mern application

Tags: node.js, nginx, cors

How can I resolve the issue of receiving multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers when making a request from the frontend to the backend?

Here is the response:-
[response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn0MS.png)

I haven't used the localhost:3000 url anywhere in the entire codebase.

I've deployed my MERN application on an AWS EC2 instance. The frontend is hosted on the domain skytrust.ca, while the backend is hosted on api.skytrust.ca. I've set up a reverse proxy using nginx and have created separate configuration files for the frontend and backend.

In the backend, here is the CORS configuration:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: "https://skytrust.ca/" }));

const allowedOrigins = ["https://skytrust.ca/"];
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const origin = req.headers.origin;
  if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
  }
  // Other CORS headers...
  next();
});

// Allow CORS for the /api endpoint
app.options("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://skytrust.ca/");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  res.sendStatus(204);
});

// Allow CORS for the /api/post endpoint
app.options("/api/post", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://skytrust.ca/");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  res.sendStatus(204);
});

// Allow CORS for the /api/user endpoint
app.options("/api/user", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://skytrust.ca/");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  res.sendStatus(204);
});
```

And here is the nginx backend.conf:
[ngninx backend config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHxwV.png)
How can I address this error when I haven't explicitly configured the localhost URL anywhere in my codebase?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)

Answer (score -1):

Check out the next things:

NGinx conf, make sure you have configured the `proxy_pass` directive correctly. It should be pointing to your Express.js backend server:

```
location /api/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
}
```

js backend conf, you have set `allowedOrigins` as an array with a single origin "https://skytrust.ca/". It should be without the trailing slash to match the origin properly

```
const allowedOrigins = ["https://skytrust.ca"];
```

Also, in your middleware function, you are checking if origin matches `allowedOrigins`, but you are not returning a response for disallowed origins. You should add an else statement to handle disallowed origins properly:

```
if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
} else {
  // Handle disallowed origins here, e.g., return an error response
}
```

In your `app.options` handlers, you are setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers multiple times for the same origin and you can simplify these handlers by setting the headers once and reusing them

```
app.options("/api", (req, res) => {
  const origin = req.headers.origin;
  if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, 
    DELETE");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, 
    Authorization");
    res.sendStatus(204);
  } else {
    // Handle disallowed origins here, e.g., return an error response
  }
});
```

Hope this helps (: