# CORS blocked when invoking 3rd party API wrapped with Azure API Management

Tags: reactjs, azure, axios, cors, azure-api-management

I have an issue that has been bothering me for almost 1 month. I'll be honest, I am not  front end developer. So here is the issue.

I have a Azure API Management that wrap 3rd party maps provider. That APIM consumed by front end developed with React.js + Axios. Every time the front end invoke API that wrapped with Azure APIM, it will be resulted error with detail:

[image]

[image]

[image]

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at ***[APIM URL]*** from origin ***[FE ORIGIN]*** has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here is my Azure APIM policy that implemented on **all operation**:

```
    <policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cors allow-credentials="false">
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>[FE ORIGIN]</origin>
                <origin>http://localhost:3000/</origin>
                <origin>http://localhost:3001/</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="300">
                <method>GET</method>
                <method>POST</method>
                <method>DELETE</method>
                <method>OPTIONS</method>
                <method>PUT</method>
            </allowed-methods>
            <allowed-headers>
                <header>content-type</header>
                <header>accept</header>
                <header>transactionId</header>
                <header>authorization</header>
                <header>userId</header>
                <header>oid</header>
                <header>userRoles</header>
            </allowed-headers>
        </cors>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <set-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" exists-action="override">
            <value>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Origin",""))</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" exists-action="override">
            <value>false</value>
        </set-header>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

And here is the part of Axios code:

```
  const handleSearch = useMemo(() => {
    const searchHandler = (value: string) => {
      if (value.length >= DELAY_CHAR) {
        const searchUrl = `${BASE_URL}?q=${value}&at=-0.789275,113.921327&limit=${MAX_ROW}`;
        axios
          .get(searchUrl)
          .then((res) => {
            const { items } = res.data;
            if (items && items.length > 0) {
              const opts: Opts[] = [];
              items.forEach((r) => {
                opts.push({
                  position: r.position,
                  value: r.address.label,
                });
              });
              setOptions(opts);
            }
          })
          .catch(() => {
            return null;
          });
      }
    };
  
    return debounce(searchHandler, DELAY_IN_MS);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [DELAY_IN_MS]);
```

I've try many options even wrapping the 3rd party API in newly created API. So I any helps really means a lot to me. Thank you very much before and I hope the information is enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)

Comment: @jub0bs I'm afraid your link does not answer my question since the origin already without trailing dash. I'm just curious, do I need to add certain header on Axios side?

Comment: Two of the origins values (`http://localhost:3000/` and `http://localhost:3001/`) listed in your Azure APIM config have trailing  slashes, which leads me to suspect that the third one (which you've redacted) also has one.

Comment: Trailing slash should not make any difference in allowed-origins as only authority is compared between what's condifured and contents of Origin header. @WulungTriyanto, can you confirm that value in Origin header matches one of the origins configured in the policy? Scheme, hostname, and port, if specified, must match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

So, after hours spend for trial and errors, we've finally find the root cause.
Notice the `<base />` on `<inbound>` part, we remove that part and viola, it success. I'll be honest I don't understand why but it solve the issue. Here is the final inbound policy:

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <!--<base />-->
    <cors allow-credentials="false">
        <allowed-origins>
            <origin>[FE ORIGIN]</origin>
            <origin>http://localhost:3000/</origin>
            <origin>http://localhost:3001/</origin>
        </allowed-origins>
        <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="300">
            <method>GET</method>
            <method>POST</method>
            <method>DELETE</method>
            <method>OPTIONS</method>
            <method>PUT</method>
        </allowed-methods>
        <allowed-headers>
            <header>content-type</header>
            <header>accept</header>
            <header>transactionId</header>
            <header>authorization</header>
            <header>userId</header>
            <header>oid</header>
            <header>userRoles</header>
        </allowed-headers>
    </cors>
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
    <set-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" exists-action="override">
        <value>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Origin",""))</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" exists-action="override">
        <value>false</value>
    </set-header>
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
</policies>
```