# blocked by CORS on production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, rest, cors

[error + whole page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xn5b.png)

im quite new to js and had now deployed my project. in development everything was working, and so now im blocked by cors when trying to signin (registering for example works for me without a problem so i know the db is connected ). there are a few thing that i dont really understand fully and i will also provide the code sample down.

heres how i use cors + signin endpoint:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin:["https://almoghasson.github.io/Face-Recognition/","http://localhost:3001"],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
  credentials: true,
}));

app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
  const { email, psw } = req.body 
  const user = { email: email } //

  postgres.select('email', 'hash').from('login')
    .where('email', '=', email) 
    .then(data => {
      const isValid = bcrypt.compareSync(psw, data[0].hash)

      if (isValid) {
        const refreshToken = uuid();
        // store token in db & cookie
        postgres.select('*').from('users')
          .where('email', '=', email)
          .update({
            token: refreshToken
          })
          .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err))

        //return user data
        return postgres.select('*').from('users')
          .where('email', '=', email)
          .then(user => {
            const { token: _, ...userWithoutRefreshToken } = user[0];
            const accessToken = generateAccessToken(userWithoutRefreshToken);
            res.cookie(REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME, refreshToken, { httpOnly: false, maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, sameSite: "none", path: '/', secure: true });
            res.json({ accessToken });
          })
          .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to get user'))
      } else {
        res.status(400).json('wrong credentials')
      }
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('wrong credentials'))
});
```

my frontend fetch:

```
fetch('https://face-recognition-api-n3yg.onrender.com/signin', {
            method:'post',
            headers : {
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: this.state.signInEmail,  
                psw: this.state.signInPsw
            }),
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            if (res.accessToken){
                const user = decodeAndStoreJWT(res.accessToken);
                this.props.setBearer(res.accessToken)
                this.props.loadUser(user)
                this.props.onRouteChange('home')
                this.props.runInterval()
            }
        })
```

i dont get why it does not accept the origin i provided , also why is the url ".../face-recognition/" but the origin does not have this part, only "...github.io"

tried adding on the front code headers the access-allow-origin header without success
tried to set the origin in my cors to "*" without success and its not recommended anyway

EDIT:
im getting this error on my server console too, if this can help:

```
Nov 1 06:41:45 PM  Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers 
after they are sent to the client
Nov 1 06:41:45 PM      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
Nov 1 06:41:45 PM      at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
Nov 1 06:41:45 PM      at ServerResponse.header (/opt/render/project/src/Backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
Nov 1 06:41:45 PM      at ServerResponse.send (/opt/render/project/src/Backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)
Nov 1 06:41:45 PM      at ServerResponse.json (/opt/render/project/src/Backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)
Nov 1 06:41:45 PM      at /opt/render/project/src/Backend/server.js:86:45
Nov 1 06:41:45 PM      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
Nov 1 06:41:45 PM    code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
Nov 1 06:41:45 PM  }
```

Comment: Does the browser's actual origin match one of the allowed origins you've listed? If your frontend app is served at https://almoghasson.github.io/Face-Recognition/, then the origin would be https://almoghasson.github.io. The Origin header doesn't include any path. It's just the protocol, domain, and port.

Comment: @LeandroLuque im sorry for the my confusion but isnt the top url and origin supposed to be the same? because this is what i thought.
i also tried adding only " https://almoghasson.github.io" to the origin list but it did not work if this is what you meant

Comment: @AntonioBalsamo And is setting an origin on cors not the way? i do be confused not gonna lie

Comment: @AntonioBalsamo this didnt fix anything sadly

Comment: @AlmogHasson the final / could also be a problem. I see it working in this way now: https://ibb.co/H4Dhh45

Comment: @AntonioBalsamo i have it like this :  origin:["https://almoghasson.github.io/face-recognition/","http://localhost:3001"], and its not changing the error

Comment: Don't forget to use the complete URL, please add "https://...".
You can try removing the final / and check it again.
As an extreme solution you can add "*" to the origins.

Comment: @AntonioBalsamo weirdly it didnt include the https part but i do have it, also i added that changing the origin to "*" also doesnt solve the problem and is not recommended.... i appreciate the help tho btw!

Comment: I see it working now without the final /. Please look for the OPTIONS request when you make the login at the Network tab in the developer tool and check the exact origin.

Comment: @AlmogHasson look here: https://ibb.co/nkHyzK1
The origin sent is "https: //almoghasson.github.io". I don't know exactly why the path is missing. You can also try just setting this value

Comment: @AntonioBalsamo i dont have options in the network tab, im using chrome im aware they removed it, tried on edge as well and its not present

Comment: @AlmogHasson please check again, I'm using Chrome too and I see it. It has the preflight type. Look at this screenshot https://ibb.co/nkHyzK1

Comment: @AntonioBalsamo https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Vvm.png this is my network tab, tried adding origin "https://almoghasson.github.io" no success

Comment: that's strange, anyway it appears browsers use the Referer header, so maybe you need to add a final /, like this: origin:["https: //almoghasson.github.io/", "http://localhost:3001"], but I'm not sure about this

Comment: @AntonioBalsamo i really tried all versions possible with this and its the same, guess ill look deeper but thank you for trying this long!

Comment: @AlmogHasson it's working now. It returns a 400 (look screenshot) but it's not blocked by CORS anymore: https://ibb.co/n6BDTX5

Comment: *"why is the url ".../face-recognition/" but the origin does not have this part, only "...github.io""* Because that's what an [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) is. URL ≠ Origin.

Comment: @gre_gor i was today years old when i found this out, thought the request is made from the url address did not know about the origin. until now i used localhost so it worked...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the origin in lowercase as the browser sends it this way.
If you use https://almoghasson.github.io/face-recognition, it works (as you can see in the screenshot below).

Furthermore, looking at your request, the origin appears to be only "https://almoghasson.github.io/".

[image: Actual origin]

So, you would like to use https://almoghasson.github.io instead of https://almoghasson.github.io/Face-Recognition/

```
app.use(cors({
  origin:["https://almoghasson.github.io", "http://localhost:3001"],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
  credentials: true,
}));
```

Here the test:

[image: CORS check]

Comment: sadly gets me the same error

Comment: I see it working now: https://ibb.co/n6BDTX5

Comment: weird i didnt change anything since the last comment, it did throw me a cors error just now and after refreshing it gave me 400, not consistent for some reason

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtw2H.png as you can see here, it gave me twice 400 and twice cors, dont really get why

Comment: same for me... I think there is something we're not considering

Comment: from what i think, it works now only is giving 400 which is a good sign, but it if u resend the request right after, my backend server doesnt rerun itself in time so it runs into cors maybe?

Comment: can you please try setting credentials: false instead of true ? I think it can cause some problems (just to make a test)

Comment: im using jwt in my project so the credentials are necessary. im working on the error no 400 right now, im not getting the cors error anymore so i guess that what i said maybe was it?

Comment: I currently see CORS errors randomly, so I'm not sure about this

Comment: yep i get that again on my end....i wonder why it acts up like that