# Preflight OPTIONS method to Cloud functions blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, cors

I am trying to build a simple app where in the front end the user uploads a .pdf file, the server receives it and further process it until it returns a firebase storage link. The front end is deployed on Firebase Hosting, and the Backend is a cloud function that also uses express. The error thrown is:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-paperfire-ada3a.cloudfunctions.net/api/upload' from origin 'https://paperfire-ada3a.firebaseapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In the network tab, it seems that the preflight OPTIONS method is failing:[image: console error]

I tried to setup cors in different ways, either using the cors() package from express, or setting the headers manually, but it didn't work in any way. Everything works from Postman, so there are not other errors in the code, and if there are, I am not sure how to find them at this point. Here is the front end ajax call:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken) {

            var form = $('#uploadForm')[0];
            var formData = new FormData(form);
            //formData.append('file', $('#pdf')[0].files[0]);
            // Perform the AJAX request
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://us-central1-paperfire-ada3a.cloudfunctions.net/api/upload',
                data: formData,
                contentType: false, // This is required for FormData with file upload
                processData: false, // Also required for FormData with file upload
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'bearer ' + idToken,
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response.extractedText)
```

And here is the cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors')
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } = require('firebase-admin/storage');
const express = require('express');
const pdfParse = require('pdf-parse');
const { OpenAI } = require("openai"); 
const openai = new OpenAI({apiKey:'api-key'});
const app = express();
var serviceAccount = require("./something.json");


const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 16 * 1024 * 1024; // 16 MB
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "databse-url",
    storageBucket: 'bucket-path'
  });

// Configure CORS
const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'https://paperfire-ada3a.firebaseapp.com/', // Adjust the origin according to your needs
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
    methods: 'GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    allowedHeaders: 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions)); // Use cors middleware

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('I GOT HERE, THE FILE IS:');
    res.send('Welcome to the PDF processing API. Use the /upload endpoint to upload files.');
});

app.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('I GOT HERE, THE FILE IS:');
    const uid = req.headers.authorization.split('bearer ')[1];
    // if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    //     // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    //     res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    //     res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    //     res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    //     res.status(204).send('');
    //   } else {
    //     res.send('Hello World!');
    //   }

    const file = req.body
...
exports.api = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest(app);
```

None of the backend code actually executes, because the OPTIONS method fails first, so I really don't know what to do next.
Many thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)

Comment: @jub0bs Unfortunately no, it doesn't solve my problem. Even though you were right, I had a trailing slash in my cors configuration at origin, I get the exact same error after removing it

Comment: At least, you're one step closer to fully resolving your issue. The next step would be to produce a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of researching, I got to the conclusion that the issue was not with my cors setup. The function was never reaching my cloud function due to Google Frontend blocking my request. The only way I was able to solve this issue was to access my cloud function from the Google Cloud console and set the permissions for Cloud functions Invoker to `allUsers`. This is a temporal solution and maybe other answers will provide more context, but the problem is solved for now. I still have to figure out a way to set this variable for production, because it is a security risk.

Comment: I came across the same problem. wondering if you've found the cause of the problem and solved it in a different way?

Comment: I'm sorry @JosephWu but I stopped investigating after posting the question and finding no answer, although the approach is still a security threat for me. If you find any solution, please let me know too. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for answering, will post it if I come across some solution!

Comment: found the solution! since I reused some existing cloud functions by copying them into this project, the function names stayed the same (the project name in the url has been updated of course). After the function deployment, I started to see these types of errors.
This morning I changed the function names and did a re-deployment, and it worked!