# Can't send a post request to my API backend from front end. I keep getting an error saying I have no CORS Access header, when I do have it

Tags: node.js, flask, npm, axios, cors

I am currently working on a Node.js integrated webserver, however when I try to sign out I constantly get these errors:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/logout' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Logout error: Network Error

Here are some of my back-end Files:

in /api/auth.py :

```
class UserLogout(Resource): 
    @JWTManager.token_required
    def post(self, public_id): 
        """Logout authenticated user by invalidating JWT refresh token"""
        
        current_user = User.find_by_public_id(public_id)

        if current_user: 
            # Get token from HTTPOnly cookies
            refresh_token = request.cookies.get('refresh_token')
            print("refresh_token")
            if not refresh_token: 
                return {'message': 'Refresh token not provided.'}, 401
            # Revoke refresh token 
            try: 
                JWTManager.revoke_token(refresh_token)
                response = make_response({'message': 'User logged out successfully.'}, 200)
                JWTManager.delete_token_cookies(response)
                response.delete_cookie('csrfToken', path='/', samesite='Strict')  
                return response 
            except TokenInvalidError: 
                return {'message': 'Invalid token: Please login again'}, 401
            except Exception as e: 
                return {'message': f'Error occurred during logout.', 'errors': e}, 500
        else: 
            return {'message': 'User not found.'}, 404
```

In my Flask webserver's innit:

```
cors = CORS()


def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Set up general app configurations
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    app.config['SOCKETIO_SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv('SOCKETIO_SECRET_KEY')

    # Set up Redis key-value db store configurations
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'redis'
    app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = False
    app.config['SESSION_USE_SIGNER'] = True
    app.config['SESSION_REDIS'] = Redis(
        host=os.getenv('REDIS_HOST'),
        port= os.getenv('REDIS_PORT'),
        # password=os.getenv('REDIS_PASSWORD'), --> USE PASSWORD IN PROD. 
        db=os.getenv('REDIS_DB'),
        decode_responses=False 
    )

    app.redis_client = app.config['SESSION_REDIS']
    

    db.init_app(app)
    csrf.init_app(app)
    socketio.init_app(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True, cors_allowed_origins="*")
    cors.init_app(app, supports_credentials=True, allow_headers=[
            'Content-Type', 'X-CSRF-Token', 'Authorization', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'
        ], resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "http://localhost:5173/*"}})

    from .auth import auth
    from website.views import views
    from .api import api_bp, initialize_routes

    # Intialize api routes 
    initialize_routes()

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')

    if not database_exists():
        create_database(app)

    return app

def database_exists():
    return path.exists('website/' + DB_NAME)


def create_database(app):
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
```

And finally, here is the front end for my logout button:

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const csrfToken = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.csrfToken.value);
  console.log(csrfToken)
  // Handle logout
  const logout = async () => {
    try {
      await axiosInstance.post(
        '/auth/logout',
        {},
        {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken,
          },
        }
      );
      console.log("post work")
      // Clear CSRF token from Redux after successful logout
      dispatch(clearCsrfToken());
      // Redirect to login page upon successful logout
      navigate('/login');
    } catch (error) {
      if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
        console.error('Logout error:', error.message);
        if (error.response) {
          console.error('Server response:', error.response.data);
        }
      } else if (error instanceof Error) {
        console.error('Unexpected error:', error.message);
      }
    }
  };
  return logout;
};
```

Any help appreciated, There is the header in the innit file, so I dont know how I keep getting the error.

- Tried reloading and downloading dependencies
- Tried changing the headers
- Tried redownloading all my dependencies

Comment: `http://localhost:5173/*` is not a valid [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked even though I've allowed https://example.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow)