CORS Error Uploading File with Presigned URL (React/CloudFlare R2) - Preflight Response Issue
I'm encountering a CORS error when trying to upload a file using a presigned URL in my React application (using Axios) to CloudFlare R2 storage. The upload works fine in Postman, but the browser throws the following error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://<bucketName>.<accountID>.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/...' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Details:

I've already tried setting AllowedOrigins to both http://localhost:5173/ and * in my CloudFlare CORS configuration.
I've included all necessary methods (PUT, GET, POST) in AllowedMethods.
I've experimented with various values for AllowedHeaders and ExposeHeaders.
MaxAgeSeconds has been adjusted to different values as well.

My current R2 CORS configuration:
[
 {
  "AllowedOrigins": [ // I already tried putting "*"
   "http://localhost:5173/",
   "http://localhost:5174/"
  ],
  "AllowedMethods": [ // I already tried putting "*"
   "PUT",
   "GET",
   "POST"
  ],
  "AllowedHeaders": [ // I already tried putting "*"
   "x-requested-by",
   "User-Agent",
   "Cache-Control",
   "Content-Disposition",
   "Content-Encoding",
   "Content-Language",
   "Content-Type",
   "Expires"
  ],
  "ExposeHeaders": [ // I already tried putting "*"
   "Content-Encoding",
   "cf-cache-status",
   "Date"
  ],
  "MaxAgeSeconds": 3600 // I already tried putting many numbers
 }
]

I've searched extensively online but haven't found a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
My React application:
import axios from 'axios';
function App() {
  const onFileChange = async (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { files } = event.target
    if (files) {
      const file = files[0]

      const uploadLink = await api
        .post('/upload', { filename: file.name, contentType: file.type })
        .then(({ data }) => data.links.uploadURL)

      console.log({ uploadLink })

      await axios
        .put(uploadLink, file)
        .then(() => window.alert('file uploaded'))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('failed to upload file:')
          console.error(err)
        })
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-screen h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
      <input type="file" onChange={onFileChange} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App

[
 {
  "AllowedOrigins": ["*"],
  "AllowedMethods": ["*"],
  "AllowedHeaders": ["*"],
  "ExposeHeaders": ["*"]
 }
]


Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow

"AllowedOrigins": [ 
   "http://localhost:5173",
   "http://localhost:5174"
  ]

  const s3Request = axios.create({
    //基础路径
    timeout: 10000
  })
  await s3Request.put<any, ResponseData<string>>(uploadLink, await file.arrayBuffer())

Try this one
