CORS Error When Adding AWS Lambda Authorizer to API Gateway
I’m facing a CORS Origin issue when accessing my microservice via API Gateway from my frontend website. The API Gateway acts as a proxy, forwarding requests to the microservice. However, I recently attached an AWS Lambda function as an authorizer for authentication, and now I’m encountering CORS issues when making requests from the Frontend.
What’s Happening:

When I call the API Gateway directly from my frontend (without the Lambda authorizer), I don’t experience any CORS issues, and the microservice returns the expected response.
Once I attach the Lambda function as an authorizer to the API Gateway(HTTP apigateway), CORS errors appear, and the browser blocks the request.
It works fine in Postman and my mobile app, which don’t enforce the same strict CORS policies as browsers.
Current Setup:


Frontend: A React-based website hosted on https://prod.example.com.
API Gateway (HTTP apigateway): Acts as a proxy and forwards requests to a backend microservice.
Microservice: Returns the response correctly when called directly.
Lambda Function: Used as a custom authorizer to validate tokens before forwarding the request to the microservice.

Lambda function code:
const jwt= require("jsonwebtoken");
const { jwtDecode } = require('jwt-decode');

module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    const authHeaders = event.headers['authorization'].split(' ');
    jwt.verify(authHeaders[1], process.env.JWT_KEY);
    const tokenData = jwtDecode(authHeaders[1]);
    
    if (tokenData.role === 'admin'|| tokenData.role === 'moderator' || tokenData.role === 'user') {
      return { isAuthorized: true };
    }
    return { isAuthorized: false };  
  }catch (err) {
    return { isAuthorized: false };
  }
}

Serverless.yaml:
org: abc
app: test-auth-lambda
service: test-auth-lambda
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  httpApi:
    cors:
      allowedOrigins:
        - https://prod.example.com
        - https://api.example.com
        - http://localhost:3000/
      allowedHeaders:
        - Content-Type
        - Authorization
      allowedMethods:
        - GET
        - OPTIONS
        - POST
      maxAge: 6000
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  environment:
    JWT_KEY: ${file(./config.${opt:stage, 'dev'}.json):JWT_KEY}
functions:
  function1:
    handler: index.handler

we have allowed the origins in serveless.yaml but there is now benfit.
allowedOrigins:
- https://prod.example.com
- https://api.example.com
- http://localhost:3000/

No Authorization header is ever present in preflight requests; such requests are not authenticated. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353729/access-from-origin-https-example-com-has-been-blocked-even-though-ive-allow

You can enable CORS on an AWS API Gateway using the API Gateway console. Follow the below mentioned steps.
1 - Choose the API Gateway on which you want to enable CORS.
2 - Choose a resource under Resources.
3 - In the Resource details section, choose Enable CORS
After you enable CORS support on your resource, you must deploy or redeploy the API for the new settings to take effect.
The above-mentioned steps will suffice you, but you can also refer to the AWS Documentation where multiple use cases regarding CORS are mentioned.
Hope this helps!
